# Получение от GeoServer полигоны пересекаемые линией ?

Tags: xml, javascript, openlayers

Помогите составить **XML** для получения от **GeoServer** всех объектов перекрываемых линией...
То есть у меня не получается разобрать пространственный фильтр - почему-то не работает...

```
var layers = mapModuleObj.map.getLayersByName(layerName);
if (layers.length > 0) {
    var url = layers[0].url || layers[0].protocol.url;
    var typeName = layers[0].params 
        ? layers[0].params.LAYERS 
        : layers[0].protocol.params.typeName;

    var points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        var pnt = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(line[i].Latitude, line[i].Longitude);
        points.push(pnt);
    };

    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
    line.srsName = "EPSG:4326";
    var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.INTERSECTS,
        value: line
    });
    var filter_1_1 = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter({version: "1.1.0"});
    var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
    var strXml = '<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    strXml += '<wfs:Query typeName="' + typeName + '" srsName="EPSG:4326">';
    strXml += xml.write(filter_1_1.write(filter));
    strXml += '</wfs:Query></wfs:GetFeature>';

    var request = new OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: url,
        data: strXml,
        callback: callback,
        failure: function () { alert("Request failed"); }
    })
};

//...

function callback(result) {
    var gmlFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3();
    var gmlLayer = gmlFormat.read(result.responseText);
    for (var i = 0; i < gmlLayer.length; i++) {
        //... обрабатываю полученные объекты
    };
};
```

На что мне возвращается:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="0" timeStamp="2013-01-11T12:11:57.017Z" xsi:schemaLocation="{...} {urt к GeoServer-у}/Geo/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Geo%3Fiels http://www.opengis.net/wfs {urt к GeoServer-у}/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:Geos="{...}" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"><gml:featureMembers/></wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Подскажите чего не хватает ?
Я предполагаю что проекции в фильтре... Но как её туда добавить не пойму...
А может я и вовсе тут накосячил... Если так, то прошу знатоков подсказать в чем...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
var layers = mapModuleObj.map.getLayersByName(layerName);
if (layers.length > 0) {
     var url = layers[0].url || layers[0].protocol.url;
     var typeName = layers[0].params 
         ? layers[0].params.LAYERS 
         : layers[0].protocol.params.typeName;

     var points = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
         var pnt = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(line[i].Longitude, line[i].Latitude);
         points.push(pnt);
     };

     var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
     line.srsName = "EPSG:4326";
     var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({
         type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.INTERSECTS,
         value: line
     });
     var filter_1_1 = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter({version: "1.1.0"});
     var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
     var strXml = '<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WF ... action.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
     strXml += '<wfs:Query typeName="' + typeName + '" srsName="EPSG:4326">';
     strXml += xml.write(filter_1_1.write(filter));
     strXml += '</wfs:Query></wfs:GetFeature>';

     var request = new OpenLayers.Request.POST({
         url: url,
         data: strXml,
         callback: callback,
         failure: function () { alert("Request failed"); }
     })
};
```